# Simple join between two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I need some help with a basic MySQL statement.

There are two tables below: meals and people.

```
TABLE meals
================================
=== id === name === meal     ===
================================
--- 1  --- John --- Pizza    ---
--------------------------------
--- 2  --- Jill --- Pasta    ---
--------------------------------
--- 3  --- Jill --- Pizza    ---
--------------------------------
--- 4  --- John --- Sandwich ---
--------------------------------
--- 5  --- Jill --- Rice     ---
--------------------------------

TABLE people
=========================================
=== name  === email           === age ===
=========================================
--- John  --- john@test.com   --- 24  ---
-----------------------------------------
--- Jill  --- jill@test.com   --- 24  ---
-----------------------------------------
--- Alice --- alice@test.com  --- 32  ---
-----------------------------------------
```

What I am trying to do is to get a distinct list of `names` from the table `meals`, and then grab only those rows from the `people` table, with the output sort order being `age` and then `email` (so if age is the same, it will do a secondary sort by email).

I am so confused!

Comment: Have you tried usnig JOIN or subquery? If yes then please share that query with us so that we can help you in fixing it.

Comment: I know it involves a JOIN somewhere, but the whole idea of joining confuses me, hence this question. I will try and work through it again now and come up with an example.

Comment: @RC - Just think about what values in ea. table would link the two tables together, do your best (even if it doesn't work) and post back.

Comment: Use `id` for a foreign key, not `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is a simple `1 to n` relationship between `people` and `meals` tables, I don't think you have to do a `distinct` and then a `group by`. All you have to do is this:

```
  SELECT p.name 
    FROM people p
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM meals m
                  WHERE m.name = p.name)
ORDER BY p.age, p.email
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this, but does it iterate through all rows in `people`, running the `SELECT` check each time? If so, this would be the wrong way round, because in my live environment the `people` table is huge and the `meals` table is much smaller. Basically it makes more sense to get the DISTINCT from meals and then use that to grab rows from people.

Comment: First, you're using a smart RDBMS like MySQL. It will not take much time to filter rows. Second, you are using `EXISTS` which is faster than `DISTINCT`. Next, I have made it simple because joining with `meals` would give you duplicate `p.name` values which will again have to be `DISTINCT`ed. If your tables are large, just run a query like this once and you'll get the difference.

Comment: Good enough for me - thanks! And I learned a new thing with `SELECT 1` too.

Comment: Yes, that is because `EXISTS` condition only checks for existence of rows, not values in their columns. As soon as the subquery fetches the first row, the condition returns true and hence it is much faster than `IN` or `DISTINCT`. So even if I do a `SELECT NULL` there, the query would run perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name.meals),email.people,age.people from meals,people 
where name.meals=name.people ORDER BY AGE;
```

Hope this helps you !

Answer (score 0):

Try like,

```
Select DISTINCT(m.Name), p.email,p.age from meals as m,people as p where m.name = p.name
```